# marshall with in restx for dictionary

Tags: python-3.x, flask, flask-restx

I have a dictionary like below

```
{
    "a": 2,
    "b": 1,
    "dd": {
        "xx": {
            "name": "Xx XxRay",
            "guid": "967436db-3f7b-40c3-94cb-45c7ac5a1787"
        },
        "yy": {
            "name": "Yy YyZee",
            "guid": "db12b2b3-554d-42a8-b34e-9995c9719999"
        }
    }
}
```

I am trying to use marhsall with in Restx , but fail to make it to work.

First, i defined the internal structure

```
details_model = api.model('Details', {

    "name": fields.String(required=True,
                          description='Name'),
    "guid": fields.String(required=False, description='GUID')
    
})
```

Secondly, I defined
which i am not using currently.

```
dd_model = api.model('dd', {
     'shortname': fields.Nested(details_model)
})
```

Finally,

```
response_model = api.model('Response', {
    'a': fields.Integer(min=0, description='Total Number of Results'),
    'b': fields.Integer(min=0, description='Total Number of X'),
    'dd': fields.Nested(fields.String, details_model)
})
```

How can i construct this structure??

Answer (score 1):

```
details_model = api.model('Details', {
    "name": fields.String(required=True,description='Name'),
    "guid": fields.String(required=False, description='GUID')
})
```

define all the sub-domains

```
dd_model = api.model('dd', {
     'xx': fields.Nested(details_model),
     'yy': fields.Nested(details_model)
})
```

Finally,

```
response_model = api.model('Response', {
    'a': fields.Integer(min=0, description='Total Number of Results'),
    'b': fields.Integer(min=0, description='Total Number of X'),
    'dd': fields.Nested(fields.String, details_model)
})
```